# How would you have an object move randomly in an area?

Tags: python, pygame

I have blitted 4 zombies to the screen in pygame. And the zombies need to wander in a specific region (let us say a 10 x 10 area) around where they were blitted. Apparently, making it so that after the player enters the said area, to have the zombie chase the player, is too difficult.

```
import pygame, random, os
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

scr_width = 1020
scr_height = 510
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width, scr_height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

images = {}
path = 'Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/'
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]
for name in filenames:
    imagename = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
    images[imagename] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, name))

pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Minigame')

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times_New_Roman', 27)

white = [240, 240, 240]

fps = 60
lives = 3
score = 0

playerX = 510
playerY = 220
playerxchange = 0
playerychange = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(8, 800)
        self.y = random.randint(8, 440)
        self.moveX = 0
        self.moveY = 0

    def move(self):
        self.speed = 3
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(images['r_zombie'], (self.x, self.y))

def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(images['r_zombie'], (x, y))

enemy_list = []
for i in range(4):
    new_enemy = Enemy()
    enemy_list.append(new_enemy)

while True:

    for enemy in enemy_list:
        enemy.move()
        enemy.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question again without improving? [How would you have a range of movement within a class in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188212/how-would-you-have-a-range-of-movement-within-a-class-in-pygame/67195231#67195231)

Comment: Wait so what exactly is Your question? in body text You mention that making "zombies" chase the player is too difficult but You don't mention that You are struggling with making them move inside the 10x10 area, so I am not understanding which problem You want to solve, anyways You should provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and before You answer go, read and execute what is said in the link. In Your case You should provide the code that should make "zombies" wander in the region and what doesn't work (since that is the question)

Comment: In the Move() method of Enemy you only set a speed, not a moving direction. In fact you now have to decide the direction (dx,dy) of the move of each enemy. Then for each frame, you add (dx,dy) to your (x,y) position. For each enemy, you'll have to decide (dx,dy). Now suppose you're in the middle. To let the zombies chase you, (dx,dy) should be in the direction of the middle, from the current position (x,y). When you want to really play, you will have to give the player in the middle a class too. It's speed and (dx,dy) must be controlled with the keyboard. Success building it !

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that makes the enemy follow the player

```
class Enemy:
def __init__(self, x, y, images, name):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.images = images
    self.animation_count = 0
    self.offset_x = random.randrange(-600, 600)
    self.offset_y = random.randrange(-600, 600)
    self.reset_offset = 0
    self.bullet_cooldown = 0
    self.health = 50

def main(self, display, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):


        if self.reset_offset == 0:
            self.offset_x = random.randrange(-400, 400)
            self.offset_y = random.randrange(-400, 400)
            self.reset_offset = random.randrange(75, 100)
        else:
            self.reset_offset -= 1

        if player_pos_x + self.offset_x > self.x]:
            self.x += random.randrange(1, 3)   
        elif player_pos_x + self.offset_x < self.x:
            self.x -= random.randrange(1, 3)   
        if player_pos_y + self.offset_y > self.y:
            self.y += random.randrange(1, 3)  
        elif player_pos_y + self.offset_y < self.y:
            self.y -= random.randrange(1, 3)   

        display.blit(image, (self.x, self.y))
```